# Rom 11:20 - What their "unbelief" was about?

Tags: romans, soteriology

Text: Romans 11:20 (ESV)

"That is true. They were broken off because of their unbelief, but you stand fast through faith. So do not become proud, but fear."

Comment: rejecting Jesus.

Comment: I think we need more details and clarity as to what you wish to know. 'Unbelief' is not 'about' anything. That is exactly it's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Paul in Rom 11:20 is referring to three things, all at Jesus' trial:

1. The crowd ask Pilate to crucify the Messiah, Jesus:

- Matt 27:22, 23 - “What then should I do with Jesus who is called Christ?” Pilate asked. They all answered, “**Crucify Him**!” “Why?” asked Pilate. “What evil has He done?” But they shouted all the louder, “**Crucify Him**!”

2. The Jews then took full responsibility for what Pilate ordered - the death of Messiah:

- Matt 27:24, 25 - When Pilate saw that he was accomplishing nothing, but that instead a riot was breaking out, he took water and washed his hands before the crowd. “I am innocent of this man’s blood,” he said. “You bear the responsibility.” All the people answered, “**His blood be on us and on our children**!”

3. The Jews rejected Jesus as their rightful, legal, hereditary and Spiritual king:

- John 19:12-15 - From then on, Pilate tried to release Him, but the Jews kept shouting, “If you release this man, you are no friend of Caesar. Anyone who declares himself a king is defying Caesar.” 13When Pilate heard these words, he brought Jesus out and sat on the judgment seat at a place called the Stone Pavement, which in Hebrew is Gabbatha. It was the day of Preparation for the Passover, about the sixth hour. And Pilate said to the Jews, “Here is your King!” At this, they shouted, “Away with Him! Away with Him! Crucify Him!” “Shall I crucify your King?” Pilate asked. “**We have no king but Caesar**,” replied the chief priests.

Thus, the Jews of the time rejected Jesus as Messiah and King, and then crucified Him.  They refused to believe in Jesus Christ.

[Important note: The fact that the Jewish leadership rejected Jesus as Messiah and king does not prevent any individual person, including a Jew, accepting Jesus as Lord, Savior, Messiah and King of their lives.  Indeed, many have, including Paul himself.]